# Call sub-reducer in default block of a parent reducer

Tags: redux, react-redux

Is it ok to have a reducer calling sub-reducers in its default block?

```
function aReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case XYZ:
      ... // know what to do
    default:
      // don't know this action, let's delegate to the children
      return {
        sub1: subReducer1(state.sub1, action),
        sub2: subReducer2(state.sub2, action)
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's absolutely legal and reasonable to do.

You might want to read through the [Redux docs section on "Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) for further ideas on how you can organize reducer logic as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the reducers in a common folder and inside that, you can combine the separate reducers into a single one like the following code.

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import Reducer1 from './Reducer1.js'
import Reducer2 from './Reducer2.js'
export default combineReducers( { Reducer1, Reducer2,... } )
```

and use the following code to use that as a single reducer.

```
import reducers from '../../reducers'(reducer's root folder name/path)
let store = createStore( reducers );
```